# Downloading user logo from Google plus server

Tags: oauth

It's part of authoraization code, that recived from Google's Plus user name, lastname and user logo. I recive by that succesfully name and last name. But user logo from generated URL have 0 bytes avalable on stream. Whats wrong?

```
                    // We have trusted token 
                    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + token);

                    /*
                    Open connection
                    */

                    try { 

            authConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (authConnection == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("Null");

              // 10 second timeout
            authConnection.setConnectTimeout(AUTH_TIMER); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            String message = "Connecton problem with Google: " + e;

            throw new Exception(message);

        } 

        try { 

            server_response_code = authConnection.getResponseCode(); // 

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            final String message = "No response: " + e;

            throw new IOException(message);

        }

        logcat.LogD(this, "Response code is: " + server_response_code);

        switch (server_response_code) { // Анализ кода ответа

            case 200: // Successful

               // get stream
                is = authConnection.getInputStream();

                if (is == null) {

                    final String detailMessage = "No stream";

                    throw new NullPointerException(detailMessage);

                }

                // Непосредственное чтение
                final String jsonResponse;

                try {

                    // reciving data from google plus by token

                    jsonResponse = readResponse(is);

                    if (jsonResponse == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null");

                } catch (Throwable e) {

                    final String message = "Json error - Google: " + e;

                    throw new IOException(message);

                }

                // Разбор полученных данных
                name = getFirstName(jsonResponse);

                if (name == null) name = "<неизвестно>";

                logcat.LogE(this, "Извлечено имя пользователя: " + name);

                family_name = getFamilyName(jsonResponse);

                if (family_name == null) family_name = "<неизвестно>";

                logcat.LogE(this, "Извлечена фамилия пользователя: " + family_name);

                photoURL = getPhoto(jsonResponse); // Получение ссылки на логотип на серверах Google

                String message1 = ""
                        + "Извлечен путь к логотипу пользователя: "
                        + logcat.safe_string(photoURL, "<пустое значение>");

                logcat.LogE(this, message1);

                if (mAuthorizationTimer != null) { // Останавливаем таймер авторизации

                    mAuthorizationTimer.cancel();

                    mAuthorizationTimer = null;

                    logcat.LogD(this, "Таймер контроля авторизации остановлен успешно...");

                }

                // Если в главной активности отсутствует логотип (взятый из кэш по email) - грузим из интернет
                if ((photoURL != null)) {

                    logcat.LogD(this, "Считываю логотип из интернет");

                    try { // Считывание логотипа из интернет

                        URL url_photo = new URL(photoURL);

                        logcat.LogD(this, "Открыт канал к логотипу...");

                        InputStream content = (InputStream) url_photo.getContent();


                        // THIS IS PROBLEM - avalable() - 0 bytes
                        if (content.available() > 0) {

                            photo = Drawable.createFromStream(content, "src");

                            logcat.LogD(this, "Успешно создано изображение...");

                        } else {

                            photo = null;

                            logcat.LogD(this, "Логотип пуст...");

                        }


                    } catch (Throwable e) {

                        final String message = "Ошибка открытия пользовательского логотипа из интернет: " + e;

                        logcat.LogE(this, message);

                        photo = null;

                    }

                }

                if (is != null) is.close();

                // Создаем новый блок данных пользователя на основе данных серверов Google
                mUser = new UserAuthData(this.getEmail(), name, family_name, photo);
```